# I really need help on part of a proof that I just don't understand!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Problem:

a) Show that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that $P(a)=P'(a)=0$ then there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $[P(x)=(x-a)^2Q(x)$.
b) Show that if $P(x)$ is a quartic polynomial then there exists at most one line $\ell$ that is tangent to the graph of $P(x)$ at two places.

I got an answer for the first part meaning that I proved that Q(x) exists. I don't understand how I can prove how there is only one tangent line to the polynomial P(x).

Comment: Can you first show that the limit of a function (if exists) is unique ? Then can you also show that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if you know the slope of a line and a point that it  passes, then you can determine that line uniquely ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $l$ and $k$ are lines, tangent to $p$ at $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$, respectively.

By part (a) of the problem,
\begin{align*}
p(x)-k(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)^2 \\
p(x)-l(x)=(x-c)^2(x-d)^2.
\end{align*}

Subtracting one equation from the other we eliminate $p$ and obtain

\begin{equation*}
l(x)-k(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^2 - (x-c)^2(x-d)^2
\end{equation*}

But the difference of two degree 1 polynomials has degree $\leq$ 1. The degree of the RHS is $\leq 1$ only if $\{a,b\} = \{c,d\}$, i.e., only if $l(x)\equiv k(x)$.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! However, since this is my first year taking calculus, would you mind explaining it in less complicated terms? for example, what is RHS? And I assume when you wrote that l(x) ≡ k(x), you meant that they are congruent to one another?

Comment: Do you understand that if $l(x)$ and $k(x)$ are equations of lines, then the difference $l(x)-k(x)$ is also the equation of a line? The right hand side (RHS) of the equation “$l(x)-k(x) = ... $” must be the equation of a line, namely, $l(x)-k(x) = mx + n$ for some constants $m$ and $n$. If you expand the RHS and set the coefficients of the quadratic and cubic terms equal to zero, you should be able to see that these restrictions imply that $k$ and $l$ intersect $p$ at precisely the same points, namely, $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$. Now, what can you say about two lines that share two points in common?

Comment: Right, I understood the first part, and thanks for clarifying what RHS means (can't believe I missed that). Regarding your last question, I believe that would simply mean that the lines intersect, am I correct? Note also in the question I'm trying to prove that there can at most be ONE line tangent to the quartic. I thought the best way to do this was to first assume that such a line exists, and use that to prove that there can't be any other line that fits the criteria. In other words, by completely proving one exists, I can eliminate all other possibilities.

Comment: If $l$ and $k$ are lines that intersect twice, then they are in fact the same line. Can you see why this is the case? Your idea of proof is essentially what is given in the answer above: given two lines, $k$ and $l$ that intersect $p$ in two places, show that they are in fact the same line, $k(x) \equiv l(x)$. This is achieved by showing that they must be tangent to $p$ at the same two points.